# Citrix with Load Runner : ctrx_get_bitmap_value returning different value while image is the same

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, citrix, loadrunner

I am using Micro Focus Load Runner to record / load test a Citrix ICA application.

I use [ctrx_get_bitmap_value](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/citrix_ica/lrFuncRef_ctrx_get_bitmap_value.htm) to wait for a screen to have the expected state.

I tried already [ctrx_sync_on_bitmap](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/citrix_ica/lrFuncRef_ctrx_sync_on_bitmap.htm) and got same issue and I read it was buggy:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lr-loadrunner/NKxDbvLz8dw

My problem is that, **on the same machine**, even if the screenshot looks the same for me, it seems the bitmap hash computed is different.

I read this about the Tolerance feature:

- [Citrix Bitmap Sync Tolerance won't work unless set to Exact](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-User-Discussions/Citrix-Bitmap-Sync-Tolerance-won-t-work-unless-set-to-Exact/td-p/610384)

But does it really work as per, since reference documentation advises not to use it:

-https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/128450_c_ctirix_replaing_tips.htm#mt-item-6

Note this is not the below issues as I am on same machine:

- https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-User-Discussions/ctrx-get-bitmap-value-returns-different-values-between-VuGen-and/td-p/604944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from further tests that:

- The Citrix cluster was load balancing strangely to another server which lead to different bitmaps due to a slight position offset in positionning
- We also had to switch to Windows Classic theme as per :

  - [Use Classic Windows Style](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/128100_c_citrix_recording_tips.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In  ctrx_sync_on_bitmap, we have to choose certain area of the screen and it will compare the bitmap of that sample with the new one to validate.
Does the screen that you compare contains some text?
Sometimes the screen with some text provide different bitmaps.

You can also try "image sync tolerance" option to low or medium in runtime settings.

[image: Hash Configuration]

Comment: thanks a lot, I read this about this feature https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-User-Discussions/Citrix-Bitmap-Sync-Tolerance-won-t-work-unless-set-to-Exact/td-p/610384, does it really work , if yes ? can you detail in answer ? I'll be happy to accept answer. See https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/128450_c_ctirix_replaing_tips.htm#mt-item-6 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this feature works, also it depends on the bitmap you comparing.
For example if you are comparing two bitmaps one with a blue background and one with black then this setting will fail for all the options but if comparing two blues with very less or negligible difference the tolerance low or medium should work.
Give it a try, i used it over an year ago ant it worked for me.
one more thing if you the sync that you placing is for a new window(pop-up) then you should try ctrx_sync_on_window function. it Waits until a window is created or becomes active.
ctrx_wait_for_event("<>");

Comment: what are the acceptable differences. In my case with human eye,  I see no difference between recorded and replayed screenshots, still it fails.

Comment: If there is very negligible difference then this option(tolerance) should work. It worked for us, we even ran the script on different LGs.
Did you gave a try to ctrx_sync_on_window?

Comment: I accepted this answer although it's not working for me. Thanks

Comment: We have made a bit of progress, and it appears issue was different. See my answer. Is it also your experience ? Thanks for your help anyway.